# Custom venv prompt not updating when activating virtual environment

Tags: python, bash, zsh, prompt, venv

I have tried to customize my virtual environment prompt by adding the following to my `.zshrc` file:

```bash
...
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
if [[ -v VIRTUAL_ENV ]]; then
    PROMPT='%F{green}(venv)%f'$PROMPT
fi
...
```

This only works if i `$ source ~/.zshrc` after activating a virtual environment.

I made it work automatically by adding the aliases below, but I was wondering if there is a better way to make this work automatically?

```bash
alias venv='source ./venv/bin/activate; source ~/.zshrc'
alias deactivate='deactivate; source ~/.zshrc'
```

Comment: Update Prompt Function: Define a function update_prompt to check if a virtual environment is active and update the prompt accordingly.  Call Function: Add update_prompt to precmd_functions array to ensure it's called before displaying the prompt. Auto-Deactivate: Set a trap to deactivate the virtual environment automatically on shell exit, ensuring clean-up.

Comment: I don't know about virtual environments, but from your code it is clear, that the variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` most exist in order to set the prompt. Since you have the code in your .zshrc, it means that this piece of code is executed either when an interactive zsh is started, or when you explicitly source it.

Comment: @sai Thanks, made it work with precmd_functions! Instead of a trap I added an else clause inside the update_prompt function to reset the prompt if no venv is detected. This way the prompt goes back to normal when deactivating.

Comment: You could put the prompt configuration into a separate file (say: `set_venv_prompt`) and source this file from your .zshrc and from your `venv` alias. Another possibility would be to put querying of the variable inside your PROMPT definition. Have a look at _man zshall_ and search for a chapter saying _CONDITIONAL SUBSTRINGS IN PROMPTS_ and the definition of the `psvar` array.

Comment: By placing the prompt configuration into a separate file (e.g., ‘set_venv_prompt’) and sourcing it from both your ‘.zshrc’ and your virtual environment alias, you can centralize the prompt setup and ensure consistency across different contexts. Another approach involves incorporating conditional logic directly into your ‘PROMPT’ definition, leveraging the capabilities described in the "CONDITIONAL SUBSTRINGS IN PROMPTS" section of the Zsh manual (‘man zshall’).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple way for your case would be to define the prompt as

```
vprompt='%F{green}(venv)%f' # Prefix for venv prompt
PROMPT='${VIRTUAL_ENV+$vprompt}'$PROMPT
```

If VIRTUAL_ENV is set during evaluation of the prompt, the `+` causes $vprompt to be printed in front of your original prompt. If VIRTUAL_ENV is unset, nothing is printed, and you only get your original prompt.